# Selenium for Python - how to get a <!DOCTYPE html> inside another <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: python, selenium

I have a website built in Wordpress. I´m developing a project to automate the upload of content to my web using Selenium for Python. I´m having a problem trying to get the XPath of a text area to writte because it is ubicated inside of another  and im unable to get the correct XPATH.

This is how im trying to get the XPATH:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
   .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                  "/html/body")))\
   .click()
```

This is the image where is shown the html code from "inspect element":
[image: This is the image where is shown the html code from "inspect element"]

Answer (score 0):

if your second webpage in iframe you can try like this

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("iframe_name"))
```

add your `iframe` name to "`iframe_name`"

after changing the this, you can use normal way to select the text area and send the data